# google maps API: need to keep poi.business persistent across zoom levels

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've seen a score of questions/answers on how to hide poi.business icons/labels from google maps, but what I need is for them to show up persistently across zoom levels.  For example, even when I have featureType poi.business styler visibility set to "on", the icon shows up in ROADMAP type but not on the same HYBRID map counterpart.  I need the icons/labels to show up on both map types at the same zoom level.

I've tried this with both the google maps API v3 as well as the static map URL formulation and the same problem shows up.  It appears the server determines that at certain zoom levels of the HYBRID map certain icons/labels should be hidden.  I would like to override this decision.  Is there a mechanism for this?  (On the HYBRID map, if I haven't been clear.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems no, at least for icon. From google docs [MapOptions object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions):

*styles | Array. | Styles to apply to each of the default map types. Note that for Satellite/**Hybrid** and Terrain modes, these styles **will only apply to** labels and geometry.*